# Error when passing a array to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Please refer the following code. 
I am trying to pass an array to a JavaScript function.

```
<?PHP
   function controller_function(){
      $data['batch_id'] = $this->input->post('batch_id');

      echo json_encode($this->Student_model->load_student_data($data));
   }
?>


//In JS
function load_data() {
    $.post("<?php echo base_url('contoller/controller_function') ?>", {'batch_id': batch_id}
        function (data)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            view_data(data[j]);
            }
        },
        "json"
    );
}

function view_data(data_array) {
    alert(data_array)
}
```

Like above when i try to alert out the `data_array`, the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` shows.

Below is the `data[j]` array.

```
Array
        (
            [stu_id] => 1
            [name] => abc
            [applied_courses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [course_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [course_id] => 2
                        )

                )
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: That looks like a PHP array to me. It is not the same as a Javascript array.

Comment: @NisargShah When i alert `data[j]['stu_id]` it was successfully alerted in `load_data` function. `data[j]['stu_id]` passing to `view_data` was success. but why i cant pass whole thing.

Comment: what is the exact error, in which line?

Comment: is your js is an external file or on page script?